# urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 422

Tags: python, python-3.x, poloniex

I am trying to utilize  https://poloniex.com/support/api/

Python [wrapper](http://pastebin.com/fbkheaRb) by oipminer:

```
self.p.api_query('buy', {"currencyPair":'BTC_STEEM', "rate":str(0.00020410), "amount":str(0.0001)})
```

But I always get 422 error:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 422
```

What do I do?

UPD:

It is no always gives an error, sometimes something like this can happen(as you can see it does not give a 422error)

```
 currencyPair:BTC_ETH, rate: 0.04816195, amount: 0.103816394477 first trade:{u'error': u'Not enough BTC.'}
```

Comment: Do you have a comma after `'buy'`?

Comment: @alecxe yes, I do, I was lost during migration to SO somehow..

Comment: Okay, no problem, edited. Does 422 happen for any `rate` and `amount` values?..

Comment: well, not any,
it works for some of them.. difficult to say now.. but

Comment: @alecxe for this: currencyPair:BTC_ETH, rate: 0.04816195, amount: 0.103816394477
first trade:{u'error': u'Not enough BTC.'}

Comment: gives not 422 error, but some other

Comment: put all this informations in question. They wiill be more readable. If you have other infomation then put them too.